# Why my loss function oscilates only in the middle

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard, loss-function

Im making a convolutional neural network and always get a loss function oscilating more in the middle, how can I fix it?
[Loss error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7NwR.png)

My data are only 100 images, I want to overfit to see that everything goes well but when getting the loss always in the central part there is a greater oscillation, I have tried to lower the learning rate but it is always the same, there is always a greater oscillation in the half of the curve, take all the 100 images in the batch size but the oscillation does not decrease, this is my code.Why can this happen? How can I fix it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

train_path='/Users/David/Deskt...'

batch_size_train=100
num_epochs=1


tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
sess=tf.Session()

#Convolutional Model

def cnn_model(features,labels,mode):


    #Capa de ingreso
    input_layer=tf.reshape(features["x"],[-1,224,224,3])


    #Capa convolucional 1........
    conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=[10,10],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu,
        name="Convolucion_1")

    #Pooling 1.........
    pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2,name="Pool_1")

    conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool1,
        filters=128,
        kernel_size=[10,10],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu,
        name="Convolucion_2")

    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2,name="Pool_2")

    conv3=tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool2,
        filters=192,
        kernel_size=[10,10],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu,
        name="Convolucion_3")

    pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2,name="Pool_3")

    conv4=tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool3,
        filters=256,
        kernel_size=[10,10],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu,
        name="Convolucion_4")

    pool4 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv4, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2,name="Pool_4")

    conv5=tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool4,
        filters=320,
        kernel_size=[10,10],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu,
        name="Convolucion_5")

    pool5 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv5, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2,name="Pool_5")

    pool5_flat=tf.reshape(pool5,[-1,7*7*320],name="Flat_Pool")

    #Deep neural network..............
    dense=tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool5_flat,units=10000,activation=tf.nn.relu,name="Capa_1")

    dense1=tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense,units=7000,activation=tf.nn.relu,name="Capa_2")

    dense2=tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense1,units=4000,activation=tf.nn.relu,name="Capa_3")

    dense3=tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense2,units=1000,activation=tf.nn.relu,name="Capa_4")

    dense4=tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense3,units=500,activation=tf.nn.relu,name="Capa_5")

    logits=tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense4,units=2,name="Capa_final")

    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=labels, depth=2)

    t=tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")

    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

    tf.summary.scalar('loss',loss)

    ds=tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=1,output_dir="/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/CNN/Model_Chekpoint",summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())

    loss_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors={"loss":loss}, every_n_iter=1)


    if mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:

        optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
        train_op=optimizer.minimize(
            loss=loss,
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,loss=loss,train_op=train_op,training_hooks=[ds,loss_hook])


    def read_file(filename_queue):

    #Funcion para leer el archivo tf.record, y retornamos el next recrod
    reader=tf.TFRecordReader()
    _,serialized_example=reader.read(filename_queue)

    #Se decodifica el tf.record retornando un diccionario 
    feature={'train/image':tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
             'train/label':tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64)}
    features=tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,features=feature,name="Decodificacion_Parse")

    #Convertimos el string a numeros de los decodificados features
    image=tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'],tf.float32,name="imagenes_decod")* (1 / 255.0)

    #Convertimos a datos
    label=tf.cast(features['train/label'],dtype=tf.int32,name="label_decod")

    #Reshape data
    image=tf.reshape(image,[224,224,3]) 


    return image,label


    def input_pipeline(filenames,batch_size):


    #Creacion de una lista de los archivos
    filename_queue=tf.train.string_input_producer([filenames],num_epochs=1,shuffle=True,name="Creacion_lista_archiv")
    images,labels=read_file(filename_queue)

    #Mezclar (shuffle) los datos de entrada
    min_after_dequeue=100
    capacity=min_after_dequeue+3*batch_size
    images,labels=tf.train.shuffle_batch([images,labels],batch_size=batch_size,capacity=capacity,num_threads=2,min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,name="Shuffle_data_in")

    return images,labels


def main(unused_argv):


#Lectura y Decodificacion de datos
img_train,lbl_train=input_pipeline(train_path,batch_size_train)

#Estimator - Modelo 
gun_detector=tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model,model_dir="/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/CNN/Model_Chekpoint")

#Inicializacion de variables y run de la session
init_op=tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init_op)

#Corremos las filas(queue) que se crearon en el grafico computacional 
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)



try:
    while not coord.should_stop():

        img,lbl=sess.run([img_train,lbl_train])

        train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            x={"x": img},
            y=lbl,
            batch_size=70,
            num_epochs=None,
            shuffle=True)

        gun_detector.train(
            input_fn=train_input_fn,
            steps=5000)


except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
finally:
    coord.request_stop()

coord.join(threads)
sess.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   tf.app.run()
```

Comment: Any code to review to actually be able to help you?

Comment: already update there is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oscillations occured due to the learning rate. If you learn to fast you'll skip over the local minimums and your loss function will be divergent. If you make your learning rate to small you will never converge or converge very slowly. You can try to fiddle around with your learning rate to get those oscillations away but then you run the risk of over training your model. Your graph looks fine to me as long as you converge In a reasonable amount of time you shouldn't care what happens in the middle.

Comment: No as long as your loss is close to zero it doesn't matter

Comment: ok thankyou, you know how I can choose the optimal size of my filters in the convolution? and the amount?

Comment: There currently is no material formula, for know you will have to use risk and error, maybe you will be the first to figure it out :)

Comment: something I do not understand, for example if I want to detect cats in a photo, in a photo the size of the cat is very small and a cat can fit in the size of the filter, but if there is another photo with a cat that fits in the whole image my filter in this case will go through the whole image looking for the features, this is something I do not understand, how can really detect with different sizes and if I should make my filter small or large in those cases

Comment: Nobody really knows what happens inside of the hidden layers of a neural network but we can make predictions. Also I suggest you read up more about how deep cvn works and the domain problem with neural networks.

Comment: you think that the more complex the image, the more oscillating the loss?